# oauth consumer files reported suspicious file

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth

I've just implemented oauth into a website and it's working great, however it seems that when people login a temporary file is created. WHM keeps emailing me to tell me about this problem:

```
Time:   Thu Dec 15 10:50:52 2011 +0000
File:   /tmp/root/openid/consumer/assoc_handle_ecde01da0a6bbfaed7f04379150d3c9f
Reason: Suspicious symlink (->/tmp/root/openid/consumer/assoc_url_988e35039cce1819e501ae6e1217c786)
Owner:  X:X (513:509)
Action: No action taken
```

Now, it's fairly obvious this is a temp file. But two questions:

1. Why is it needed to login people in? (purely for my knowledge)
2. How can I get it out of that folder or ensure it doesn't keep symlink'ing

The oauth is processed by Zend Framework's library

Comment: problem seems to be with the framework rather than oauth.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi yea i agree, just need to know why ZF is doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the reasoning behind the temp files, this is from the Zend [OpenID Introduction](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.introduction.html#zend.openid.introduction.how):

> The OpenID consumer establishes an optional association with the
>   provider using Diffie-Hellman keys. As a result, both parties have a
>   common "shared secret" that is used for signing and verification of
>   the subsequent messages.

Since it is optional, you can disable it by passing true as the second parameter to Zend_OpenId_Consumer to put it in "dumb mode" where it :

```
$consumer = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer(null, true);
```

Here are the caveats of dumb mode:

> OpenID Authentication supports both a "smart mode" and "dumb mode" to accomodate Consumers of differing capabilities. A smart Consumer does a little more work at the beginning to save itself work later, but requires local caching of state information. A dumb Consumer is completely stateless, but requires extra an HTTP request. [Source](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#smart_vs_dumb)

You can control the location of the cache files as well to avoid the whm warnings.

```
$path        = '/home/you/zend/application/data';  // dir to store associations
$authStorage = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer_Storage_File($path);
$consumer    = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer($authStorage);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I can see that many files will be created for these requests, so is it best to periodically clear the cache folder? Will it affect logins/logouts?

Comment: You can clear it periodically, if an active identity file is removed, the session will revert to dumb mode.  If you could clear it based on how long its been since the file was modified I think that would be a safe option as well.